# Vuejs - How to get the current id in a url of an api with axios

Tags: vue.js, get, axios

When the client clicks on the button, I want him to block another client, so I want my id to be dynamic: http://example/user/:id.

My template:

```html
<template>
    <div class>
        <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <div>
                <div>{{ post.name }}</div>
                <div>{{ post.id }}</div>
                <button @click='BlockUser'>Block</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And my script:

```html
<script>
   const axios = require('axios');
   
   export default {
       name: 'User',
       data() {
           return {
               posts: [],
               errors: [],
               id: {
                   id: ""
               },  
           }
       },

       methods: {
           getData() {
               axios.get(`http://example/user`)
               .then(result => {
                   this.posts = result.data
                   console.log(result)
               })
           },

           BlockUser() {
               axios.get('http://example/user/blacklist/:id' + encodeURIComponent(this.id.id))
               .then(response => {
                   console.log(response)
               })
           },
       },
   }
</script>
```

Initially, I set a value for the id in data id a number and it worked. But now that I put an empty string.
it returns an undefined

Comment: Now, he shows me: http://example/user/blacklist/%20+

Comment: what i understood, you want id to be dynamic and should be present in url ? like `http://example/user/blacklist/20`. am i right ?

Comment: Yes. For good blacklist the right person

Comment: simply do axios.get('http://example/user/blacklist/'+encodeURIComponent(this.id.id)).. it should work

Comment: It does not work... it's the same line as my main post. Maybe is it because of my data?

Answer (score 0):

If your posts have user_id field inside, you can pass it to BlockUser method, and use it in the request url.

```
<button @click='BlockUser(post.user_id)'>Block</button>
```

```js
           BlockUser(user_id) {
               axios.get(`http://example/user/blacklist/${user_id}`)
               .then(response => {
                   console.log(response)
               })
           },
```